# Feasibility of using angular js for web app with over 200 medium to complex screens

Tags: angularjs, performance, memory

My team was considering using angular js for web app UI development. But knowing at a high level how single page apps work, I had a question as to, how feasible it is to use angular js framework, for a large web application. this would have at least 200 screens, each screen containing an average of 30 UI controls like text boxes, calendar controls, drop downs etc.

The user will be accessing the web app on  desktop or laptop and will be using the application in the browser throughout an 8 hour day, without ever closing the browser.

Given above usage, would angular js, memory usage / performance be issue?

are there web apps with huge and complex UI, built using angular js, that are in production and used everyday?

Comment: I am more interested in knowing if angular js app having 200+ screens will do ok on memory consumption by browser. any known issues with angular js apps imposing large memory requirements on client browser desktops/laptops?

Comment: Google DoubleClick Campaign Manager is written in Angular. I suggest having a look at Writing a Massive Angular App at Google NG Conf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have not just 200 but 1000's of screens - this number does not matter as long as you address the core and fundamental questions below. They all boil down to memory and performance.

1. At a given point of time how many $watches will be active.
2. At a given point of time how many listeners are created.
3. At a given point of time what is the complexity of DOM i.e. the number of DOM elements and thee nesting/depth.
4. At a given point of time how many Javascript modules (services, controllers etc.) will be loaded in the memory. Even though these things are singletons they consume memory.
5. For each such screen how much memory will be consumed (if you use jqueryUI etc. your memory increases quite rapidly than pure angular + html components)

This brings to what you can do to control the above factors which if not watched will make your application sink/crash.

1) How do you break the run-time complexities of your "big" application ? You can now think of "Routers" or dialogs. Each of your screen will come-and-go i.e. you will never display 200 screens the same time.

2) Make sure when the screen is gone there is no "leftover". Don't use jQuery - if you do make sure you clean this on $scope.$destroy.

3) Multitudes of directives:- Directives are powerful but don't over use it - try not to deep nest too many of them. templateUrl is "tempting" but sometimes in-lining a template is the best choice. Use build tools that will inline the templates.

4) Load modules on demand using requireJS. This will force you to modularize your application and think hard about concatention strategy (combining JS files). Will force you to write independent modules.

5) Browser caching your assets and a good cache busting mechanism. Grunt based plugins are to your rescue. Minify your assets.

6) Compresss the assets for efficient network utilization and faster transmission.

7) Keep your app encapsulated in Angular. Don't create any global objects. Chances are that they have access to some closure or are referring to some things within angular $scope and $scopes are now still hanging on or are in difficult trajectory to be able to get Garbage Collected.

8) Use one-time-bind or bind-once model binding as much as possible.

9) Splash screen is an excellent weapon - us it.  Helps you load some stuff upfront while the user watches smooth/jazzy picture/picture :)

**Regarding 8 hours a day constant use**

Unless there is a leak of the following kind you should be fine:-
1) Listeners leaking i.e. hanging around.
2) DOM leaks. Detached DOM issue.
3) Size of Javascript objects. Javascript objects coded in a certain way creates repeated instances of function.

(I am developing AngularJS app - with more than 450 screen - MDI like app. The app is not yet in production. The above points are coming from my burnouts in the functionality we have developed so far.)

Comment: many thanks for the tips.  will act on all of them. Did you use any tools for finding memory leaks in browser or just to find memory consumption at any given point in time. Please point to some good tools for monitoring angular app memory consumption and performance

Comment: Chrome developer tools are good. Ability to take snapshots of memory dump and compare against each other is great.

Answer (score 4):

I've worked on multiple projects that are extremely large single-page applications in Angular and Ember.JS at companies like McKesson an Netflix.

I can tell you for a fact that it's completely "feasible" to build "huge, complex" applications with frameworks such as Angular. In fact, I believe Angular is uniquely well suited to this because of it's modular structure.

One thing to consider when creating your Angular application is whether or not every user will benefit from all "200 pages" of your application. That is to say, is it necessary to have all 200 views be part of the same single page application? Or should you break it into a few single page applications with views that share concerns.

A few tips:

1. Watch out for name collisions in the IOC container: If you create enough services and controllers, even if you break them into separate modules, it's very easy to create two services with the same name. This may or may not result in an outright error. What happens when you register two "fooService" services? The last one wins.
2. If you decide to break your app into more than one single page app, you have to be sure you have solid boundaries of functionality between the two. They're not going to be able to share state easily other than with something like cookies or local storage.
3. If you decide to keep everything in one single page app, you're going to want to keenly watch your initial download time. Always check to see how long it takes to start your app "cold" over a slow-ish connection. If the entire app is in one bundle, depending on how you structure things (are you going to use AMD?) then you might see a long initial load time.
4. *AVOID rendering HTML on your server.* I can't stress this enough. Let Angular do that work for you. The only rendering your server should be doing is rendering JSON to be returned from some RESTful service.
5. Flush out your JS build process early on. Look into Node-based tools like Grunt, Gulp, and Broccoli for linting/concatenating/minifying your JS files. Checkout Karma for running unit tests, and look into Istanbul for code coverage. Protractor is a great tool as well, but I recommend strong unit tests in Karma over integration tests with Protractor just because Web Driver based tests tend to be brittle.

Other than that, I think you'll find a single page app written in any modern framework to be extremely snappy after the initial load is done. In fact, it will make any "old" PHP/ASP.Net style app that renders the entire page at the server seem slow as dirt in comparison. This is because you'll only be loading data and the occasional .html file over HTTP.